# VBA Fixed workbook to various workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I think I'd like to do my everyday things easier. I do not have any wide knowleadge of VBA so i use it with "record VBA".

I have 2 workbooks:
(1) "DATABASE.xlsx" - fixed which always collect data
(2) many workbooks i.e. "xxx.xlsx" , "yyyy.xlxs", "zzzz.xlsx" etc. - variable workbook, changing every time depends on what i copy from the workbook (1) - I will open (2) manually by myself

My issue is how to write my VBA to copy data from (1) to various workbooks (2). I do not know how to define the (2) workbooks which alwyas change. I can choose (2) workbooks manually. It does not have to be something really professional. It's only about coping from (1) to (2)....

I have done as below:

```
Sub Makro10() ' ' Makro10 Makro ' ' Klawisz skrótu: Ctrl+Shift+X '
    Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:H1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("xxx.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("xxx.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("xxx.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("xxx.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False End Sub
```

It's working for only specific (2) workbook "xxx.xlsx", but i would like to use it for various (2).
I'm asking for support, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have any specific column in workbook (1) that determines which workbook (2) the data should be pasted in?

Comment: The issue is that (2) are in many localications in many folders - which do not have any cohesion in file path names etc.... so i prefer to open it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is by replacing all the instances of `Windows("xxx.xlsx").Activate` with `Workbooks(2).Activate` in your code.

But you have to make sure that no other workbooks are open as the code can accidentally reference another workbook based on how you opened excel files. So technically, you need to open workbook (1) first which is DATABASE.xlsx. Then open whichever workbook (2) you need and run the code.

```
Sub Makro10() ' ' Makro10 Makro ' ' Klawisz skrótu: Ctrl+Shift+X '
Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:H1").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(2).Activate
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(2).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(2).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("DATABASE.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1:B1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(2).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False End Sub
```

What is happening here is that VBA references the 2nd workbook that was opened (which is workbooks(2)) and pastes the data there as per the code. in your earlier code, because you recorded it, it was always using xxx.xlsx file because that is how you recorded it.

I would suggest that if possible save the code in DATABASE.xlsx and save the file as a macro file (DATABASE.xlsm). That way, you can open workbook (1) and workbook (2) (whichever one you want) and run the code from workbook (1).

Hope this helps! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Makro2()
'
' Makro2 Makro
'
' Klawisz skrótu: Ctrl+Shift+X
'
    Dim OthWB As String

    Windows.Application.ActiveSheet.Select
    OthWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks("202102 PO.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:H1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks(OthWB).Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks("202102 PO.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks(OthWB).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks("202102 PO.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks(OthWB).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks("202102 PO.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks(OthWB).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

@Bharath Raja
Thanks for your answer. I will try your solution also

I was thinking also about issue & found the resolve. We must active (2) workbook & then it is defined as OthWB. Maybe somebody uses it also.

Comment: Great job on figuring it out. Idea is the same. But in your code it copies data from "202102 PO.xlsx" and pastes in the current file where the macro is running. Thats all.